# Using lengthconvert with siunitx S column

Tags: tables, siunitx, lengths

I need to align numbers in a table. The numbers are generated from the `\Convert` command from the `lengthconvert` package. I want to use an `S` column from the `siunitx` package to align the numbers, but this doesn't work. Following is a MWE.

The first error reported is `Argument of \tl_clear:N has an extra }`. I suspect that `\Convert` is not fully expanded when read by the `S` macro. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S}
    \Convert[number-only, unit=cm]{100pt} \\
    3.14 \\
    2.71828
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No; the `\Convert` command, despite being defined with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` is not fully expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\Convert` command is not fully expandable, despite being defined with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` (which is an error in the package).

There's a simpler way using a built-in function in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% \usepackage{xparse} % already loaded by siunitx

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertdim}{mm}
 {
  \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #2 } { 1#1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.5,group-four-digits]}
    \convertdim{cm}{100pt} \\
    3.14 \\
    2.71828
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A fancier version where you can state the number of decimal digits (with rounding):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertdim}{O{2}mm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #3 } { 1#2 } , #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.5,group-four-digits]}
    \convertdim{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[0]{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[1]{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[2]{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[3]{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[4]{cm}{100pt} \\
    \convertdim[5]{cm}{100pt} \\
    3.14 \\
    2.71828
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn` returns at most five decimal digits (but the last digit is not necessarily accurate).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I get an error: ./Untitled.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
\convertdim #1#2->\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {#2}{1#1}
l.14     \convertdim{cm}{100pt} \\

Comment: Okay, looks like `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn` was not added to expl3 until July 15 2014. I'm using TeXLive 2014 release June 14 2014. :-(  Any suggestions that will work for TeXLive 2014 distribution?

Comment: @mrclary Why don't you update? Is it a TeX Live provided by some package manager (Debian, Fedora or similar) or the TUG one?

Comment: I may just have to update. However, I'd like to keep a standard TeXLive 2014 distribution as well, so I'll have to install a new distribution that is reserved for these types of minor updates. I've always used MacTex for my distribution installations, so I'll have to figure out the best way to go about this.

Comment: @mrclary My concept of “standard” TeX Live is an updated one.

Comment: Touche! I updated.