# TeX/LaTeX: Macro for getting a length as number

Tags: macros, expansion, lengths, dimensions, fp

I would like to write a macro `getlengthin` to get a length or dimen as floating point number in a specified unit. Here is what I have created so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcount\lengthcount
\newcount\unitcount
\def\getlengthin#1#2{%
    \lengthcount=#1%
    \unitcount=\dimexpr1#2%
    \FPdiv\result{\the\lengthcount}{\the\unitcount}%
    \result%
}

\def\a{\getlengthin{\paperwidth}{mm}} % \edef does not work here !

\begin{document}

    \a

    \getlengthin{\paperwidth}{mm}

    \getlengthin{\textheight}{mm}

\end{document}
```

For some reason I need to calculate the length in the preamble and I tried to use `edef`, but `edef` does not work with my macro. What is the problem here?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26806/27635

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A modification of my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213027/4427

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertdim}{O{2}mm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #2 } { 1#3 } , #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\getlengthin}{O{2}mm}
 {%
  \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=#1]{\convertdim{#2}{#3}}{#3}%
 }

\begin{document}

\convertdim{\paperwidth}{pt} -- \getlengthin{\paperwidth}{pt}

\convertdim[5]{\paperwidth}{in} -- \getlengthin[5]{\paperwidth}{in}

\convertdim[3]{\paperwidth}{cm} -- \getlengthin[3]{\paperwidth}{cm}

\end{document}
```

For both commands the optional argument is the number of digits for the rounding.

The first command is fully expandable, so it can be used in other contexts where a decimal number is needed.

[image]

See also the `lengthconvert` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your `convertdim` command does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this:

> 8.50 in
>   193.30 mm
>   19.3 cm

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getlengthin}[3][]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{#2}% Capture length
  \setlength{\@tempdimb}{1 #3}% Capture unit
  \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2,#1]
    {\calc{\strip@pt\@tempdima/\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}{#3}% Divide length by unit
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\getlengthin{\paperwidth}{in}

\getlengthin{\textheight}{mm}

\getlengthin[round-precision=1]{\textheight}{cm}

\end{document}
```

`\getlengthin[<options>]{<length>}{<unit>}` takes additional `<options>` from [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

---

If you wish to perform conversions between lengths without really printing them, you can set them directly without problem:

```
\setlength{<length register>}{<length in whatever unit you want>}
```

So, for example, `\setlength{\mylen}{12in}` will set `\mylen` to 12 inches, but internally convert it to points (something you don't have to worry about). Or, `\setlength{\mylen}{\dimexpr 3cm+2in-5pt+3bp-1mm}` if you want an expression containing multiple units of measure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my problem is not completely solved yet: I need to calculate the length in the preamble, but when I add `\edef\a{\getlengthin{\paperwidth}{in}}` after `makeatother` and `\a` after `\begin{document}` I still get an error.

Comment: @PatrickS: If you just want to "calculate the length in the preamble", then you don't need to use a conversion. Set them using `\setlength{<length register>}{<length in whatever measurement>}`.

Comment: "Calculate the length" was not the right term, I am rather trying to "read" the length in a specific unit in the preamble. The `convertdim` command from egreg's answer did the job. Anyway, thank you for your help.