Rounding dimensions to specific decimal places

In How to typeout dimensions in mm?, a custom command is suggested to typeset dimensions in a given unit. Sometimes, it is desirable to typeset the length to one or two decimal places
I want an output similar to the above except that number of decimal places is determined by an optional argument in the command \printlengthas
\documentclass{article}


% printlengthas
% BEGIN_FOLD

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand { \printlengthas } { m m }
{ \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {#1} { 1 #2 } \hspace{2pt} #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff 

% END_FOLD

\begin{document} 
    
\newlength{\advertwidth} 
\setlength{\advertwidth}{1mm}

\noindent%
\printlengthas{\advertwidth}{mm}
\newline
\printlengthas{\advertwidth}{pt}

\smallskip

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r @{\space}l l @{\hspace{2pt}}l@{}}
    
    One
    & decimal place
    & 2.9
    & pt
    \\
    
    Two
    & decimal places
    & 2.85
    & pt
    \\
    
    Three
    & decimal places
    & 2.845
    & pt
    \\
    
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}


This question is similar to: Using lengthconvert with siunitx S column. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Egreg's second version takes the number of decimal places as an optional argument: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213027/29873

@DG'. I found the answer in the thread you suggested
